# The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following simple view. Why is it resulting in this error?

`The view auth_lifecycle.views.user_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

```
"""Renders web pages for the user-authentication-lifecycle project."""
from django.shortcuts               import render
from django.template                import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth            import authenticate, login

def user_profile(request):
    """Displays information unique to the logged-in user."""

    user = authenticate(username='superuserusername', password='sueruserpassword')
    login(request, user)

    render(request, 'auth_lifecycle/user_profile.html',
           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Because the view must **return** `render`, not just call it.  (Note that  `render` is a simple wrapper around an [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse)). Change the last line to

```
return render(request, 'auth_lifecycle/user_profile.html',
           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

(Also note the [`render(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) function returns [a `HttpResponse` object behind the scenes](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f30c7e381c94f41d361877d8a3e90f8cfb391709/django/shortcuts.py#L17-L25).)

Answer (score 15):

```
if qs.count()==1:
        print('cart id exists')
        if ....

else:    
        return render(request,"carts/home.html",{})
```

Such type of code will also return you the same error this is because 
of the intents as the return statement should be for else not for if statement.

above code can be changed to

```
if qs.count()==1:
        print('cart id exists')
        if ....

else:   

return render(request,"carts/home.html",{})
```

This may solve such issues

Comment: what are you sugesting the 2 code snippets are just the same

Comment: i have faced  the same error that is mentioned in the question but i got due to the intents  as in the first code the return statement is for the second if statement but not for the first thats the reason i got  
"that view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

when i set it to first if statement then it worked

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: Python is sensitive to code indentations. because of the code indentation in the first version, the `return .. render()` is only called in the `else...` part of the if ..else. In the second version, there is no indentation and so the `return  render()...` always executes.

Answer (score 6):

I know  this is very late to post something here but this may help out someone to figure out the silly mistake.

That there are chances that you are missing `return` before `render()`. please make sure that.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error using an UpdateView

I had this:

```
if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
    form.save()
    form2.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

and I solved just doing:

```
if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
    form.save()
    form2.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('adopcion:solicitud_listar'))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Django, every view is required to return an [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) (or one of its subclasses). However, it is common to use the [`render(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function to [render templates in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render). Using `render(...)` ensures that the view will not encounter errors, as `render(...)` returns an HttpResponse internally.

Coming to this specific case, you're missing a ***`return`*** statement, and thus the view did return ***`None`***, which caused the exception.

So, adding a `return` statement will solve the issue, as below

```py
def user_profile(request):
    # your code
    return render(...)
    ^^^^^^
```

---

#### Troubleshooting

Many people face this issue; their code/logic may differ, but the reason will be the same. Here are a few scenarios that may help you to troubleshoot the situation,

1. Have you missed adding a `return` statement?

```
def user_profile(request):
    HttpResponse("Success")  # missing a `return` here
```

2. Are you sure the returned object is a `HttpResponse` or its a subclass? Some people may return the model object or form object directly from the view

```
def user_profile(request):
    my_model_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('id'))
    # at last, return a model instance
    return my_model_object
```

3. Does all your `if...else` clauses properly return a `HttpResponse`? (In the following example, It is not clear what should return,

   a. in case the `form.is_valid()` is `False`

   b. in case the `form.is_valid()` is `True` (after `form.save()`)

```
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        return render(
            request,
            "user_profile.html",
            {"form": UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)},
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is very sensitive to indentation, with the code below I got the same error:

```
    except IntegrityError as e:
        if 'unique constraint' in e.args:
            return render(request, "calender.html")
```

The correct indentation is:

```
    except IntegrityError as e:
        if 'unique constraint' in e.args:
        return render(request, "calender.html")
```

Comment: this cannot be right

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but resolved it by returning the render after saving the data.

```
    error_message = None
    if not first_name:
        error_message = "first name is required!!!!"
    elif len(first_name) < 4:
        error_message = "first name must be more than 4 characters!!!"

    elif not error_message:
        signup_obj = Signuup(firstname=first_name, lastname=last_name, email=email, password=password)
        print("here is the complete object!!!!")

        signup_obj.register()
        

    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'error': error_message})
```

**Issue:** After saving data if I do not have any **error_message** to show but I am not returning anything after saving.

**Solution** Error solved after adding

```
  signup_obj.register()
  return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

In the code....