# The view course.views.coursehome didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Unable **redirect** the "return redirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={"id": instance.id}))" page. I think problem has thi line "**return redirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={"id": instance.id}))**".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Ae8.png)

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def coursehome(request,courseid):
    courseid=get_object_or_404(CourseId,courseid=courseid)
    instance=get_object_or_404(CourseDetails,courseid=courseid)
    scorm_type=get_object_or_404(scormcontent,courseid=courseid)
    cohome=CourseDetails.objects.filter(courseid=courseid)
    scormcourse=scormcontent.objects.filter(courseid=courseid)
    course_enroll=Enrollment.objects.filter(courseid=courseid)
    student_data=course_enroll.filter(student_id=request.user.id)
    user_id=str(request.user.id)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        for student in course_enroll:
            if user_id in student.student_id:
                home={
                        'courseid':courseid,
                        'cohome':cohome,
                        'scormcourse':scormcourse,
                        'student_data':student_data,
                        "scorm":scorm_type,
                        }

                return render(request,'course_home.html',home)
            else:
                return redirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={"id": instance.id}))
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="registration/login.html"), name="login"),
    path('', course.views.index, name='Home'),
    path('index',course.views.index),
    path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

```
path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
path('profile/',views.view_profile,name='profile'),
path('users/',views.getuser,name='getuser'),
path('profile/password/',views.change_password,name='change_password'),
path('profile/edit/',views.edit_profile,name='edit_profile'),
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    views.activate, name='activate'),
path('activate-mail/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/activate_mail_sent.html')),
path('activated/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/activated.html')),

url(r'^contact/$',msg.messages, name='contact'),
path('blog/',course.views.blog,name='blog'),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$',course.views.coursedesc,name='detail'),

url(r'^course-home/(?P<courseid>[-\w]+)/$',course.views.coursehome,name='coursehome'),
url(r'^course/(?P<courseid>[-\w]+)/$',course.views.playscorm,name='playscorm'),
path('store_data/',course.views.store_data,name='store_data'),


path('terms-of-service/',course.views.termsofservice,name='termsofservice'),
path('about/',course.views.about,name='about'),
url(r'^requirements/(?P<courseid>[-\w]+)/$',course.views.requirements,name='requirements'),
url(r'^schedules/(?P<courseid>[-\w]+)/$',course.views.schedules,name='schedules'),
# url(r'^exam/(?P<courseid>[-\w]+)/$',course.views.exam,name='exam'),
url(r'^progress/(?P<courseid>[-\w]+)/$',course.views.progress,name='progress'),
# url(r'^add_question/(?P<courseid>[-\w]+)/$',course.views.add_question,name='add_question'),
url(r'^messages_list/$',msg.messages_list,name='msg_list'),
url(r'^message/(?P<id>\d+)/$',msg.get_message,name='msg'),
```

Comment: Could you share your urls.py?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258905/the-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-instead)

Comment: That is not working for me @ArakkalAbu

Comment: I have shared urls.py @kamilyrb