# Django - Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Why i am getting this error? **Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`** how do i solve this ?

my Homepage/api/views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from Homepage.models import EducationLevel
from Homepage.api.serializers import EducationLevelSerializer

@api_view(['GET', ])
def api_detail_educationlevel(request):

  try:
    education = EducationLevel.objects.all()
  except EducationLevel.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    if request.method == "GET":
      serializer = EducationLevelSerializer(education)
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

Homepage/api/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from Homepage.models import EducationLevel
class EducationLevelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EducationLevel
        field = ('Sequence', 'Description', 'Status')
```

my Homepage/api/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from Homepage.api.views import api_detail_educationlevel

app_name='educationlevel'

urlpatterns = [
  path('', api_detail_educationlevel, name="detail"),
]
```

my main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('api/educationlevel/', include('Homepage.api.urls', 'educationlevel_api')),
]
```

UPDATE

when i tried this

```
def api_detail_educationlevel(request, slug):
      try:
        education = EducationLevel.objects.get(id=slug)
      except EducationLevel.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i get this error

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258905/the-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-instead)

Comment: @Compro Prasad no

Answer (score 1):

Your view needs to return a `HttpResponse` object but your code doesn't.

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def api_detail_educationlevel(request):
    try:
        education = EducationLevel.objects.all()
    except EducationLevel.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = EducationLevelSerializer(education)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The `if` statement should be written outside the `except` block. Small issue easy to overlook.

The above code is also somewhat redundant. The decorator `@api_view(['GET'])` will anyway check if `request.method` has value `GET` or not. So, you can remove the redundant check. The resulting code will become:

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def api_detail_educationlevel(request):
    try:
        education = EducationLevel.objects.all()
    except EducationLevel.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    serializer = EducationLevelSerializer(education)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Edit: As pointed out by @youngminz you don't need to do exception handling if you are getting all objects without any filter conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is your Except block. In your response, you have not passed any data but just status. I would suggest passing an empty string as data with status

Comment: how do i do that? even though i have this ? "" education = EducationLevel.objects.all() ""

Answer (score 0):

The error you are talking about is when the return value of the view is None.

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def api_detail_educationlevel(request):

  try:
    education = EducationLevel.objects.all()
```

The above code `EducationLevel.objects.all()` never raises `EducationLevel.DoesNotExist` exception, as the Django Queryset does lazy evaluation. So, the following exception handling process is not executed.

```
  except EducationLevel.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    if request.method == "GET":
      serializer = EducationLevelSerializer(education)
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

... In python, if function doesn't specify a return value, it returns `None`. This is why `Expected a Response, HttpResponse or HttpStreamingResponse to be returned from the view, but received a <class 'NoneType'>` error is raisen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check all your conditions so that all of them are "Responsed"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).