# ValueError: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, web

I have been getting the valueError where post_edit returns None instead of an HttpResponse object.

**This is my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, request
from django.urls import reverse
from markdown import Markdown
from django import forms

from . import util

md = Markdown() 


class createPage(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'cols': 60}))
    description = forms.CharField(label="Description", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 120}))

def pages(request, name):
    page_name = util.get_entry(name)
       if page_name is None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/invalidPage.html", {
            "title": name.capitalize()
        })   
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/wikiPages.html", {
        "page": md.convert(page_name),
        "title": name
    })

def post_edit(request, name):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = createPage(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            description = request.POST.get('description')
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            description = form.cleaned_data["description"]
            util.save_entry(title, description)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pages', kwargs={'name': title }))
    else:
        description = {
            'title': name,
            'description':util.get_entry(name)
        }
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", description)
```

**My edit.html**

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }} | Edit
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{message}}

    <form action="{% url 'post_edit' title %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="title">Title:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" cols="60" required disabled value="{{title}}" id="title"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="description">Description:</label></th>
        <td>
            <textarea name="description" cols="120" rows="10" required id="id_content">{{ Description | linebreaksbr}}</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**My urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("wikiPLUS/new/", views.post_new, name="post_new"),
    path('wikiPLUS/edit/<str:name>', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    path("<str:name>", views.pages, name="pages"),
    
]
```

I have been getting the error:
[The view encyclopedia.views.post_edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUMTj.jpg)

I am very new to Django. I hope I could provide relevant information for question and error.

**Edit**
I applied the following changes on post_edit function then it worked:

```
def post_edit(request, name):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = createPage(request.POST)
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        
        util.save_entry(name, description)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pages', kwargs={'name': name }))
    else:
        form = createPage() # this will create empty form if it is a GET request
    description = {
        'title': name,
        'description': util.get_entry(name)
    }
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", description)
```

Comment: You may not need that ***else....*** clause there

Comment: I tried deleting the else clause, save and ran. but the error still persists

Answer (score 1):

In `post_edit` function add:

```
else:
  form = createPage() # this will create empty form if it is a GET request
description = {
            'title': name,
            'description':util.get_entry(name)
        }
return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", description)
```

Indentation of description(your context dictionary) and render should be at same as else.

For more info. like when this errors usually occurs, you may check these answers [The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258905/the-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-instead)

Comment: On indenting the render and description the same as to else, the error no longer persists, however now I cannot get the post_edit function to work properly. Every time i edit the description and press the edit button the same page (blank description box) appears and edits are not saved

Comment: Try changing form's action to action="."