# why does my form validation not work in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to make it so that if the user already exists then log in the user else return error message. I read the documentation and implemented it into my own project. I get error: "The view sign_in.views.sign_in didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import SignInForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages

def sign_in(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignInForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = SignInForm()

    username = request.POST.get("username")
    password = request.POST.get("password")

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("boom-home")
        messages.success(request, f"Signed in as {user}")
    else:
        return messages.error(request, f"Failed to sign in as {user}.")

    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "sign_in/sign_in.html", context)
```

NOTE: usually this error is because people do not put "return" before the "render" method but I do put return.

Comment: `return messages.error(request, f"Failed to sign in as {user}.")` This line is the cause of your error.

Comment: Also your code flows very badly even if the request is not of the method POST you still try to get the values and authenticate anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much!. Although that was not the problem. the problem was that in the "else" statement I put "return" before the messages.error() and you're not supposed to do that.

Comment: so your saying I should move the code inside the "if request.method == 'POST' block"? (the code that checks if user is not None)

Comment: @Caleb: you are also not using the form to validate and clean the data. You can work with `form.is_valid()` and `form.cleaned_data[''username]` to validate and retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the following lines

In the following link you can see more about this problem

[The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258905/the-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-inste)

```
def sign_in(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  <---Add (Example)
           return redirect('home')<---Add (Example)
    else:
        form = SignInForm()
```