# Django ValueError - didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django Framework. I just want to save employee data using a form. But I always get this error no matter what I adjust in my code. `ValueError at /employees/create_employee/ The view employees.views.create_employee didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` Here are my codes:

Project folder:
[image]

**models.py - employees**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

# Create your models here.
class Employee(models.Model):
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 sex = models.CharField(max_length=20)
 position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 division = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 created_at = models.DateField(default=date.today)
 updated_at = models.DateField(default=date.today)
```

**employees/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Employee

class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Employee
    exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at']
```

**employees/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import EmployeeForm

# Create your views here.
def create_employee(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('employee_list') # redirect to list view or another page
    else:
        return render(request, 'employee_form.html', {'form':form})
```

**employees/templates/employees/employee_form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Create Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Create Employee</h1>
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**employees/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('create_employee/', views.create_employee, name='create_employee'),
]
```

**project's main urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('employees/', include('employees.urls'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258905/the-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re-render the template with the invalid form in case the form is invalid:

```
def create_employee(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(
                'employee_list'
            )  # redirect to list view or another page
    else:
        form = EmployeeForm()
    return render(request, 'employees/employee_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: still the same error :(

Comment: @Eli: so `render` is *outside* the `else` part?

Comment: yes. sometimes it says - TemplateDoesNotExist at /employees/create_employee/

Comment: @Eli: well then it means the template you refer to (`employee_form.html`) does not exists. Where is that one defined?

Comment: i think it is in employees/views.py

Comment: the employee_form.html is in employees/templates/employees/employee_form.html

Comment: @Eli: then it is `render(request, 'employees/employee_form.html', {'form': form})`.

Comment: can you edit your code above so that i can accept your answer? thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

please check using this approach

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import EmployeeForm
def create_employee(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('employee_list') # redirect to list view or another page
    form = EmployeeForm()
    return render(request, 'employee_form.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: indention error for this line - return render(request, 'employee_form.html', {'form': form})